# JPA merge member of collection not working

Tags: jpa, collections, merge, eclipselink

JPA merge: not working for member entities.

```
public classs SalesOrder {

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true,  fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
            mappedBy="salesOrder", 
            targetEntity=OrderItem.class)
    @OrderBy("id asc")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}


public class OrderItem {
    @ManyToOne
    private SalesOrder salesOrder;
}


EntityManager em = ...;
// start transaction
OrderItem orderItem = em.find(OrderItem.class, 1);
orderItem.setPrice(1234);
em.merge(orderItem);   // not working

SalesOrder salesOrder = orderItem.getSalesOrder();
salesOrder.setTotalPrice(5567); 
em.merge(salesOrder); // working

// commit transaction
```

Changing the OrderItem was not working and its persistence was not changed.
Changing the salesOrder worked. Even after merging the salesOrder, the orderItem was not changed in persistence. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

EDIT: after trying, detach the orderItem before making changes, it works.

```
    OrderItem orderItem = em.find(OrderItem.class, 1);
    em.detach(orderItem); // why need to detach it first???
    orderItem.setPrice(1234);
    em.merge(orderItem);   // working
```

But it will impact performance since the orderItem is already managed. After detached, it will have to be loaded again.

Comment: used a flush() ? log entries? if an object is "managed" then calling "merge" is utterly pointless

Comment: It should commit the changes to persistence at the end of transaction. flush() is required?

Comment: detach it first, working. But it is a painful workaround

Comment: flush is only required if you want to check the changes BEFORE commit. If your assessment of "not working" is actually made after commit then ignore flush. But, as said, you did a find, so it is managed, so "merge" is not needed at all.

Comment: clearly any observation also depends on what setPrice and setTotalPrice do ...

Comment: How does the OneToMany come into it, or does the code in the edit not work without the detach call?  Show the logs with EclipseLink logging set to finest when running without the detach call, and make sure to log the value you are changing before and after you change it.